# Standard SQL in bigrquery

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use R's [`bigrquery`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigrquery) package to get some data from BigQuery into an R session. However, my query is written in BigQuery's [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) rather than its legacy SQL dialect. How do I tell the package to run the query using Standard rather than legacy SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See example below

```
insert_query_job <- function(query, project, destination_table = NULL,
    default_dataset = NULL,
    create_disposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
    write_disposition = "WRITE_EMPTY",
    useLegacySql = FALSE)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (it tells me `useLegacySql` is an unused argument). Do I need a particular version of the package for this to work?

Comment: It appears that even the dev version of the package doesn't support this yet. But there's fork and a pull request that does. Install via `devtools::install_github("backlin/bigrquery", ref='feature/useLegacySqlOption')`