# Cannot reference a SQL view in a Legacy SQL query using R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, google-bigquery

I am trying trying to use dplyr to access/manipulate a table view in Google BigQuery. However when I try to aggregate the table using dplyr functions (select, filter, etc.) I get this error:

> Error: Cannot reference a SQL view in a Legacy SQL query

The code below is to illustrate what I am trying to do.

```
#source the table
pd = src_bigquery(project, dataset) %>%
 tbl(table)

#get a aggregated view of the table that is filtered on a specific date
pdSelect = pd %>%
 select(id, date) %>%
 filter(date =="2017-03-15") %>%
 collect()
```

Is there a way to not use legacy SQL when using dplyr?  For example, in the Google Bigquery web UI it says "By default, BigQuery runs queries using legacy SQL. Uncheck this to run queries using BigQuery's updated SQL dialect with improved standards compliance."  When I am working in that environment I typically just unselect it so it stops using legacy SQL.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Edit: it should be possible to use standard SQL by putting the `#standardSQL` shebang at the top of your query.

Original response:
It looks like there is no option in the [source for the BigQuery connector with dplyr](https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery/blob/master/R/dplyr.r) to use standard SQL, and the `#standardSQL` shebang doesn't work. There was an [issue submitted in relation to useLegacySql](https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery/issues/134) that you could upvote or comment on, or you could consider [submitting a pull request](https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery/pulls).

Comment: It looks like someone created this [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278705/standard-sql-in-bigrquery) that might solve the problem.  This is the code `devtools::install_github("backlin/bigrquery", ref='feature/useLegacySqlOption')` that should do this trick.  However, it has not been added to the latest CRAN version of bigrquery.  I am also not sure that it will work with dplyr.

Comment: If you do figure out something that works, please post an answer so that other users will be able to find the solution as well :)

Comment: This has [since been fixed](https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery/issues/147) and the #standardSQL [should now be working](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql).

Answer (score 0):

As well as passing in the shebangs you can set the `use_legacy_sql` flags into `bigrquery` and `dplyr` connectors. This can be useful if you're accessing a view that was built with standard SQL.

**bigrquery**

Pass the use_legacy_sql flag to `query_exec`:

```
bigrquery::query_exec("SELECT * FROM `datasetName.standardSQLView`", 
                      project ='bQProjectName',
                      use_legacy_sql = FALSE)
```

**dplyr**

Pass the use_legacy_sql flag to `dbConnect`:

```
bQCon = DBI::dbConnect(bigrquery::dbi_driver(),
                       project = 'bQProjectName',
                       dataset = 'datasetName',
                       use_legacy_sql = FALSE)
dplyr::tbl(bQCon, 'standardSQLView')
```